# How to compare and select non-changing variables in panel data

Tags: loops, stata, panel-data, data-management

I have unbalanced panel data and need to exclude observations (in t) for which the income changed during the year before (t-1), while keeping other observations of these people. Thus, if a change in income happens in year t, then year t should be dropped (for that person).

```
clear
input year id income
2003 513 1500
2003 517 1600
2003 518 1400
2004 513 1500
2004 517 1600
2004 518 1400
2005 517 1600
2005 513 1700
2005 518 1400
2006 513 1700
2006 517 1800
2006 518 1400
2007 513 1700
2007 517 1600
2007 518 1400
2008 513 1700
2008 517 1600
2008 518 1400
end

xtset id year
xtline income, overlay
```

To illustrate what's going on, I add a `xtline` plot, which follows the income per person over the years. ID=518 is the perfect non-changing case (keep all obs). ID=513 has one time jump (drop year 2005 for that person). ID=517 has something like a peak, perhaps one time measurement error (drop 2006 and 2007).

[image]

I think there should be some form of loop. Initialize the first value for each person (because this cannot be compared), say t0. Then compare t1-t0, drop if changed, else compare t2-t1 etc. Because data is unbalanced there might be missing year-obervations. Thanks for advice.

**Update/Goal:** The purpose is prepare the data for a fixed effects regression analysis. There is another variable, reported for the entire "last year". Income however is reported at interview date (point in time). I need to get close to something like "last year income" to relate it to this variable. The procedure is suggested and followed by several publications. I try to replicate and understand it.

**Solution**:

```
bysort id (year) : drop if income != income[_n-1] & _n > 1
```

Comment: @NickCox thanks for advice. I updated my question. If you like, I can provide you with reference for this particular approach. Best regards

Comment: I'm doing an empirical replication study. Following a procedure that several papers used before. For training purpose. I cannot see the statistic-ethical problem here. Replication is a core element of empirical research. Best regards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
bysort id (year) : gen byte flag = (income != income[_n-1]) if _n > 1
list, sepby(id)
```

The procedure is *VERY IFFY* methodologically. There is no need to prepare for the fixed effects analysis other than `xtset`ting the data; and there rarely is any excuse to create missing data... let alone do so to squeeze the data into the limits of what (other) researchers know about statistics and econometrics. I understand that this is a replication study, but whatever you do with your replication and wherever you present it, you need to point out that the original authors did not have much clue about regression to begin with. Don't try too hard to understand it.

Comment: I am very happy to endorse this answer, which echoes my doubts.

Comment: The procedure is supposed to be used by several papers according to the OP but I personally never have come across this before. Is this discussed in any books?

Comment: @PearlySpencer in Gutiérrez-i-Puigarnau, E., & van Ommeren, J. N. (2010). Labour supply and commuting. Journal of Urban Economics, 68(1), 82-89. they account for endogeneity of distance by using employer-induced changes in distance (in their identification strategy). To infer causality they apply worker-residence-fixed effects. If reported commuting distance changes (no change in residence and job), you might assume a firm relocation (exo. variation) - and you are still left with possible measurement error due to self-report. Then comes this selection procedure into play. Best Regards, Marco

Comment: Bah. You can just as well assume construction on the bridge across a major river. Or conclusion of Boston's Big Dig. And title the paper "The impact of infrastructure projects on labor supply".